# Are biblical posts allowed?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Puzzling Stack Exchange post: [Which one of you is Jesus?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32682/which-one-of-you-is-jesus)

I just posted this and I'm unsure if using biblical references would be an OK thing for this SE.

Comment: Considering we have an [entire site](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/) for biblical studies, I don't think there's any problem using biblical references. On the other hand, I'm not at all sure what the [trivia] tag means in this context. Does it mean a person with detailed knowledgeable in the New Testament should have access to the solution? If so, the puzzle seems kinda boring.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with using references to anything. The reason for the downvotes is that it's not really a puzzle - it's *just* trivia with nothing else attached to it.